# How can I get data from joined tables using fetchxml

Tags: sql, fetchxml

I have two tables Tasks and Notes

**`Tasks`**

```
| Id | Task |
|----|------|
| 1  | task1|
| 2  | task2|
| 3  | task3|
```

**`Notes`**

```
| Id | TaskId | Text |
|----|--------|------|
| 1  | 1      | text1|
| 2  | 1      | text2|
| 3  | 1      | text3|
| 4  | 2      | text4|
| 5  | 2      | text5|
| 6  | 3      | text6|
```

I want the result of the fetchxml to be:

```
[ {Id: 1, Task: "task1", Notes: ["text1", "text2", "text3"]},{Id: 2, Task: "task2", Notes: ["text4", "text5"]},{Id: 3, Task: "task3", Notes: ["text6"]}]
```

I know how to do it using SQL, struggling to find any help to do it using fetchxml
can anyone please help me?

Comment: actually fetchxml is related to Dynamics CRM, you mean that query - correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT n.TaskId as Id,t.Task,
group_concat(n.Text) end AS Notes
FROM tasks t,notes n
On t.Id=n.TaskId
WHERE 
group by n.TaskId,t.Task
```

I am writing fetchxml below

```
 Select
     n.TaskId as [@id],
     t.Task as [@Task],
    
    (
    Select
     group_concat(n.Text) as [@Notes],
    
    FROM tasks t,notes n
    On t.Id=n.TaskId
    WHERE 
    group by n.TaskId,t.Task
    FOR XML Raw('notes'),TYPE
    )
    
    FROM tasks t
    WHERE 
    group by t.Id,t.Task
    
    FOR XML PATH('tasks'),
    ROOT('myFetchXml')
```